# Do I need to escape a string when using preg_match?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using a simple HTML web form that collects a username and password. I am using `preg_match` to only allow A-Z, 0-9 characters to be used for the username. I am using the following code below:

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $_POST["username"]))  {
    echo '<script>alert("Usernames can only contain A-Z, 0-9")</script>';
}
```

Do I need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` in order to escape this string? If so, will it still work in all cases? If not, what security risks I am exposing myself to and how can I prevent them?

(I am escaping the username before putting it into my query and database)

Comment: Why would you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` if you are not interacting with a mysql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should never use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Just forget that this function even exists.**

If you are putting PHP variables in the SQL then even if you escape them you are not doing this properly. You must use parameter binding and do not modify the input in any way, unless your business logic requires it.

To prevent SQL injection (which I assume is your goal) you must use placeholders and parameter binding. In mysqli it looks something like this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username, passwordHash) VALUES(?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
```

I recommend to switch from mysqli to PDO. It offers more and is simpler to use. In PDO the same example would look like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username, passwordHash) VALUES(?,?)');
$stmt->execute([$username, $password]);
```